# WPF StackPanel PNG Capture not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I am attempting to create a png capture of a `StackPanel`, however when I save, I am getting a distorted view where all the content is black rectangles, and the size is not correct. The width and height are correct in the image save, however all the content is forced to the top and squished together

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:POExpress.Views" x:Class="POExpress.MainWindow"
Title="My Window" Height="500" MinWidth="1000" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="My Epics">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Border Margin="0,52,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="sp_ports" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <Button x:Name="btn_capture" Content="Save to png" Margin="0,10,114,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="31" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="99" Click="Btn_capture_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

```
public RenderTargetBitmap GetImage()
{
    Size size = new Size(sp_ports.ActualWidth, sp_ports.ActualHeight);
    if (size.IsEmpty)
        return null;

    RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(sp_ports), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
        context.Close();
    }

    result.Render(drawingvisual);
    return result;
}

public static void SaveAsPng(RenderTargetBitmap src)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.Filter = "PNG Files | *.png";
    dlg.DefaultExt = "png";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
        using (var stream = dlg.OpenFile())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}

private void Btn_capture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveAsPng(GetImage());
}
```

[image]

What it should render as (with some info blacked out)
[image]

Comment: What does it look like on the screen? It's difficult to see how all that content is supposed to fit in that small image and look good.

Comment: What happens if you substitute the actual height and width of mainGrid?  Which, by the way, is a terrible name for a border.

Comment: I have been copying and pasting "mainGrid" around trying to see what component I can render instead.

Comment: mainGrid contains a ScrollViewer, so the height of that is much smaller because it doesnt included non-rendered

Comment: @redcurry added capture of what it should look like

Comment: I should note, if I do the render at the scroll viewer level or higher, it renders correctly, but only the visible area

Comment: Is this all your code? It works fine for me. Did you check if `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` have the desired values? As a note, you don't need to call `context.Close()` when it is disposed of by a `using` block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All `UIElements` inherit from `Visual`, so you can feed your `StackPanel` to the `Render` method directly.

```
public RenderTargetBitmap GetImage()
{
    Size size = sp_ports.DesiredSize;
    if (size.IsEmpty)
        return null;

    RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    result.Render(sp_ports);
    return result;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @Clemens, there are some subtle intricacies to using the `UIElement` directly. His other comment, however, is the million dollar one.

```
Size size = uiElement.DesiredSize
```

Gives us the size of the visible portion of `uiElement`.

```
Size size = new Size(uiElement.ActualWidth, uiElement.ActualHeight)
```

Returns the full size of `uiElement`, also extending in the non-visible range.

Given you've run into this problem, you're after the latter. The main gotcha is you'll need to reevaluate the visual before rendering. Currently, you're projecting the full visual to the desired size (the visible part) of the `UIElement`.

```
public RenderTargetBitmap GetImage(FrameworkElement element)
{
    Size size = new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
    if (size.IsEmpty)
        return null;
    element.Measure(size);
    element.Arrange(new Rect(size));

    RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(element), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
    }

    result.Render(drawingvisual);
    return result;
}
```

*I use `FrameworkElement` to incorporate `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.*

---

**UPDATE 2**

> As soon as I change the size of the stack panel, the screenshot gets hosed again. It seems to remember whatever the longest state was and squishes based on that.

After some fiddling around I was able to reproduce your issue. It occurs when the `StackPanel` has to extend to fill any remaining space. The solution is to give the `uiElement` infinite space to calculate its desired size, which relieves us from the dependency on actual sizes.

```
public RenderTargetBitmap GetImage(FrameworkElement element)
{
    element.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    element.Arrange(new Rect(element.DesiredSize));

    Size size = element.DesiredSize;
    if (size.IsEmpty)
        return null;

    RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(element), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
    }

    result.Render(drawingvisual);
    return result;
}
```

I've checked `Expander` behavior (ref test app) but couldn't find anything funny going on there.

---

For completeness, here's my test app.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public RenderTargetBitmap GetImage(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            element.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            element.Arrange(new Rect(element.DesiredSize));

            Size size = element.DesiredSize;
            if (size.IsEmpty)
                return null;

            RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

            DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
            {
                context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(element), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
            }

            result.Render(drawingvisual);
            return result;
        }

        public static void SaveAsPng(RenderTargetBitmap src)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "PNG Files | *.png";
            dlg.DefaultExt = "png";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
                using (var stream = dlg.OpenFile())
                {
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Btn_capture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveAsPng(GetImage(sp_ports));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Btn_capture_Click">Take Pic</Button>
        <StackPanel x:Name="sp_ports">

            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="H1" Width="40"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="H2" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="400" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Background="Red"/>
                <Expander Grid.Row="1" ExpandDirection="Down" IsExpanded="False">
                    <TabControl Height="400">
                        <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
                            <TextBox FontSize="50" TextWrapping="Wrap">Text for Tab 1</TextBox>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                            <TextBox FontSize="50" TextWrapping="Wrap">Text for Tab 1</TextBox>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Expander>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue"/>
            </Grid>

            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="H1" Width="40"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="H2" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: This only works correctly when the element has zero Margin. Using a VisualBrush is generally the better approach.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for saving the day. Been banging my head against a wall on this one

Comment: Spoke too soon it seems. As soon as I change the size of the stack panel, the screenshot gets hosed again. It seems to remember whatever the longest state was and squishes based on that